# maxtimeout Reached - Indexing a document Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

recently when I try to index a document. The request, response with max-timeout reached
after a certain point in time, and it starts indexing again. 
Now, I'm trying to find the root cause of that issue. The only thing I'm able to find is one of my master nodes was down at that time. will it result in that timeout issue?
the infra details of my elastic search are:
run in Kubernetes
3 data nodes - each node spec(ram 64GB memory limit 32GB) - heap size - 28GB disk size - 1TB
3 master nodes - each node spec(ram 16GB memory limit 4GB) - heap size - 4GB disk size - 10GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause of it 
which is due to all masters being down at that time

because of multiple issues:

- heap dump saving (out of mem in storage)
- because of storage sharing trying to dump heap data with the same name(which throws file exist error)